# Convert JSON to Excel file with php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, json, excel, pdo

I have this file which give me JSON output from mysql database:

```
<?php

require 'core/init.php';
$general->logged_out_protect();

$username   = htmlentities($user['username']); 
$user_id  = htmlentities($user['id']);


    try {


      $result = $db->prepare('SELECT ID,br,sufiks,kupac,datum,rok,status FROM racuni WHERE user_id=:user_id');
      $result->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
      $result->execute();
      //$res = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        /* Extract the information from $result */
        foreach($result as $r) {
          $temp = array();
          // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
          $temp['ID'] =  (int) $r['ID']; 
          $temp['br'] = $r['br'].$r['sufiks'];

          $temp['kupac'] = (string) $r['kupac'];
          $temp['datum'] = (string) $r['datum'];
          $temp['rok'] = (string)$r['rok'];
          $temp['status'] = (string)$r['status'];

               //   $rs = $db->prepare('SELECT sum(radnih_sati) FROM track_radnici WHERE user_id=:user_id AND id_radnika=:id');
         // $rs->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
        //  $rs->bindParam(':id', $r['ID']);
          //$rs->bindParam(':radnici', $radnici); 
         // $rs->execute();
        //  $sumRows = $rs->fetchColumn(); 
        //  $temp['7'] = (int) $sumRows;



          // Values of each slice

          $rows[] = $temp;
        }


    $table['data'] = $rows;


        $jsonTable = json_encode($table);

    //echo $jsonTable;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    echo $jsonTable;


    ?>
```

and everything is fine this code give me this output:

```
{"data":[{"ID":1,"br":"1-2015","kupac":"ADAkolor","datum":"2015-05-19","rok":"2015-05-21","status":"placeno"},{"ID":2,"br":"2-2015","kupac":"Milenk","datum":"2015-05-27","rok":"2015-05-28","status":""}]}
```

How I can convert this JSON output to Excel file? What is the best way to do this? Or some other way witout JSON? What you suggest?

Comment: If you want it to excel, you can just use `INTO OUTFILE` and generate a csv that Excel can read. Maybe you need actually .xlsx file?

Comment: Please write this as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is deviating from your request as it does not involve `JSON`.

If you want it to excel, you can just use `INTO OUTFILE` and generate a `csv` that Excel can read. Maybe you need actually .xlsx file?

Example

```
SELECT ID,br,sufiks,kupac,datum,rok,status 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/excel.csv'
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' -- this is tab separated
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM racuni WHERE user_id=:user_id;
```

If you want the columns to come along you have to add this line before the SELECT like this.

```
SELECT 'ID','br','sufiks','kupac','datum','rok','status' 
UNION
SELECT ID,br,sufiks,kupac,datum,rok,status 
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/excel.csv'
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' -- this is tab separated
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FROM racuni WHERE user_id=:user_id;
```

I am not sure it will work but give it a try.

```
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT ''ID'',''br'',''sufiks'',''kupac'',''datum'',''rok'',''status'' 
    UNION
    SELECT ID,br,sufiks,kupac,datum,rok,status 
    INTO OUTFILE ''C:/excel.csv''
    CHARACTER SET latin1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''\t''
    LINES TERMINATED BY ''\r\n''
    FROM racuni WHERE user_id=:user_id;');
      $result->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id); 
      $result->execute();
```

Then the iteration is most likley not needed?

Comment: please implemet this int my code from question. Where I need to put this query?

Comment: Do you have a editor? Like Workbench? Its just a regular syntax, so try putting it in `prepare('SELECT 'ID','......FROM racuni WHERE user_id=:user_id;')`

Comment: I get: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'C' (T_STRING) in /home/agroagro/public_html/netRacuni/getracunicsv.php on line 13

Comment: also how this can be saved to user computer but user browser need to ask where to save excel file?

Comment: I als try this code: $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, $jsonTable);
fclose($out); but when I run code nothing happend